# Proving $\theta$ is zero if and only if $\theta X=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> A one form  $\theta$ is zero if and only if $\theta X=0$ for all $\mathscr{X}(M)$. A vector field is zero if and only if $\theta X=0$ for all $\theta\in\mathscr{X}^* (M)$

$\rightarrow$ If $\theta=0$ then $\theta X=X(0)=0$.

$\leftarrow$ If $\theta X=0$ then $\theta X=X(\theta)=0$ implies that the specific $\theta$ must be zero once $X$ is arbitrary vector field.

$\rightarrow$ If $X=0$ then $\theta X=0$.

$\leftarrow$ If $ X=0$ then $\theta X=X(\theta)=0$ implies that the specific $\theta$ must be zero once $\theta$ is arbitrary one form field.

**Question**:

Are my proofs correct? This seems to be too straightforward. If not can you explain how to prove the assertions?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

In the comments, it was suggested to write in local coordinates. So consider $\zeta=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ on a neighborhood $U$ of $p$.

Then $\theta(X)=\theta_p(\sum X_p(x_i)\partial_i)=\sum(X_p(x_i)\theta_p(\partial_i))=\sum dx_i(X_p)\theta_p(\partial_i)$

The last expression is only 0 if $\theta(\partial_i)$ is zero for every coordinate that is if $\theta=0$.

Comment: ok… but the point of the exercise is to explain why $\theta(X)=0$ for all $X$ implies $\theta=0$ (likewise with the dual statement).

Comment: What does $X(\theta)$ mean? And no, your proof consists in stating what is to be proved as fact. I used to call this “proof by intimidation.”

Comment: @TedShifrin    I think it would mean this  $d\phi(X)=X(\phi)$

Comment: @peek-a-boo If $\phi=0$ then $d\phi(X)=X(\phi)=0$. I do not know why they write $\theta$ on the book without the differential.

Comment: you have proven 2 out of the four statements. The two of them being true by linearity (which you ought to mention). But still, the other two, you haven’t explained why they are true. You’re still asserting it is true without any proof.

Comment: $\theta$ is a $1$-form, not a function. You are not understanding what’s going on.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Nope, not so.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to consider coordinates. This is, take any $p\in M$ and a chart $(U,\varphi=(x^1,\dots,x^m))$ (I assume $m=\text{dim}(M)$) for that point. Compute $\theta X$ (the same with the others) with those coordinates and, hopefully, the proof will be clear for you (during the process you will need to use that $dx^i(\partial/\partial x^j)=\delta^i_j$ and linearity).

Comment: @Yester Please see my edit.

Comment: the local proof, as it stands, doesn’t really work. You’re going to have to invoke some bump-functions to make the domains of the things you’re testing against be all of $M$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo How do I do that? Can not I just say, that if it works for this arbitrary chart, it works for the others too?

Comment: @peek-a-boo, let us know if this helps. For any point $p\in M$, consider some vector field $X$ such that $X_p=x^i(p)\partial_i|_p$, where $x^i$ is a function of the coordinates. Then, if $\theta|_p=\sum_j\theta^j(p)dx^j|_p$, we have $\theta|_p(X|_p)=\theta^i(p)$. By assumption, $\theta(X)=0$, therefore, $\theta|_p(X|_p)=\theta^i(p)=0$. This is true for any point and any $x^i$. Then, $\theta^i=0$ for any chart, then, $\theta=0$.

Comment: I'd like to point out that it suffices to prove this at each point $p \in M$, so the question and proof become purely linear algebraic. If you fix $p$, then $X(p) \in T_pM$ and $\theta(p) \in T_p^*M$. $V = T_pM$ is a vector space and $V^* = T^*_pM$. It is not hard to show that it suffices to prove the following: $\ell \in V^*$ satisfies $\ell=0$ if and only if for any $v \in V$, $\ell(v)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to help with the direction $\theta = 0 \Rightarrow \theta X = 0 \forall X$. You should write out each detail yourself to be very sure you understand why in fact it is true.

So let us consider the direction $\forall X \theta X = 0 \Rightarrow \theta = 0$. This is equivalent to the contrapositive, if $\theta \neq 0$ then there exists some $X$ such that $\theta X \neq 0$. (Why the contrapositive? Because it can be easier to construct something to show existence.)

What does $\theta = 0$ mean? It means that in all local coordinate charts, all its coordinate functions equal zero. So if $\theta \neq 0$, then there exists at least one coordinate chart $x_i$ where $\theta = \theta_i dx^i$ and at least one $\theta_i \neq 0$.

Now can you build a vector field $X$ such that $\theta X \neq 0$?

> Take a bump function $\phi$ supported on the open set associated to the coordinates $x_i$. Define $X$ by $X_i = \phi\theta_i\partial_i$ in the coordinate set and $X = 0$ out of it. Then the function $\theta X$ is also supported on the open set associated to the coordinates and can be computed in those coordinates: $\theta X = \sum \theta_i dx^i(\sum \phi\theta_j \partial_j ) = \phi \sum \theta_i^2 > 0$ at at least one point, as there is at least one $\theta_i \neq 0$.